# Google Cloud Platform: How to remove download access for a bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts, bucket

I want my service account to be able to create files and folders in my bucket but disallow any read/list/download for objects in that bucket. I am not able to figure out what permissions to set for my bucket/service-account. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the general [Identity and Access Management (IAM) page for Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam). From that, you can either use one of the predefined Cloud Storage roles, or create a custom role with the specific IAM permissions that you need. Let's follow both approaches:

- **Standard Cloud Storage IAM Roles:** [in this page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) you can find the complete list of available IAM Roles. Given the use case you present, you should consider using `roles/storage.objectCreator` role, as it only grants `storage.objects.create` permissions, and you cannot view or list objects.
- **Custom IAM Roles:** you can follow [this guide to create a custom IAM Role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles), and the define the specific permissions that you want to grant to your bucket. [In this other page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions) you can see a list of all the available permissions. You should use `storage.objects.create`, but you may be interested in adding also a different permission such as `storage.objects.delete` in order for the Service Account to be able to overwrite content (which cannot be done with the `roles/storage.objectCreator` role, as it does not have *delete* permissions).

So in general, and applying your specific use case, you could say that you can use the `roles/storage.objectCreator` standard role. However, you must take into account that using it, you will not be able to override content, as for that purpose, you will need the `storage.objects.delete` permission too. In that case, you can create a custom role.

Comment: I tried using the storage.objectCreator permission but the problem with that was that I could create files directly in the bucket but could not create any files in the folders of the bucket as that needs list permission. On granting that I was able to download files as well. So in this case what should I do?

Comment: I guess the error is that when you upload files to a folder in a bucket, you are doing something like `gsutil cp file gs://bucket/folder`, which prompts the error regarding the requirement of list permissions. However, you should instead use `gsutil cp file gs://bucket/folder/`. Cloud Storage does not have the concept of directories, and instead, has a "flat" storage system that performs the distinction between files and "folders" as we know them by the fact of having a `/` at the end. So in order to upload to a "folder", you just have to append the folder name (and `/`) to the directory.